# Dynamically Change Data of Partial View while maintaining code bound to parent View/Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm stuck trying to wrap my head around how to make a page like this work. My model contains a list of objects which have text fields for different languages. There's a spot in the view that needs to be dynamically changed to display the text fields associated to the language selected in a drop-down list. The text fields also need to be editable such that when the parent form is submitted, the text fields need to save correctly in the parent model after being edited in the partial view/model. I was hinted in another page that partial views is what I should try to do, maybe something about programmatically generating partial views for each language in the list, and doing something to update/render the correct partial view based on the selection in the drop down list...?

My initial attempt led me to try using ajax calls to the controller to return the correct partial view based on the value of the drop down menu, but I can't bind it to the model, and hence can't update/save it when the main view form is submitted. Here's what I've been working with so far:

Model:

```cs
    public class EditModel
    {
        public List<TextField> TextFieldList;
        public List<string> DisplayList
            {
                get
                {
                    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
                    foreach (TextField a in TextFieldList)
                    {
                        tempList.Add(a.Language.ToString() + "/" + a.Currency.ToString());
                    }
                    return tempList;
                }
            }
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
    public ActionResult EditTextFields(int adId, int index)
    {
        Ad ad = this.Repository.GetById(adId);
        return PartialView("EditTextFields", ad.TextFieldsList[index]);
    }
```

Main View:

```cs
    @model Models.EditModel
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(href('DisplayList').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).find(':selected').val();
            var adId = GetId();
            $.get('/Controllers/EditTextFields', "{\"adId\": " + String(adId) + ", \"index\":\"" + value + "\"}", function (data) {
                $('#TextFieldDiv').html(data);
            });
        }));
    });

    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Widget", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "WidgetEditForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DisplayList)
        </div>
        <div id="TextFieldDiv">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("EditTextFields", (TextField)@Model.TextFieldList[0]);}
        </div>
    }
```

Partial View:

```cs
    @model Objects.TextField
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldName" style="vertical-align: top;">
            Headline Text:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Headline)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Headline)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldName">
            Sub-Headline Text:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubHeadline)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubHeadline)
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    }
```

Ideas to point me in a good direction?